# Google chart query language does not filtering date range data

Tags: google-visualization

Observed some strange behaviour from google chart query filter.

Query :

```
    sqlQuery = "sql?tq=select * where execution_date >= '" + startDate + "'  and execution_date <= '" + endDate + "' &sqlQueryID=daily_runs"
```

This works only for 1 month and it is not filtering out the date range.

When i have a data from Mar 1 to  Mar 30 - It is filtered and displayed.

Query :

```
   "sql?tq=select * where where Date >= 'Mar 25, 2016' and Date <= 'Mar 31, 2016' &sqlQueryID=daily_runs"
```

Result : > 0 rows

When i have a date from Mar 1 to Apr 1 - It is not filtered and returns 0 rows.

Query :

```
   "sql?tq=select * where where Date >= 'Mar 25, 2016' and Date <= 'Apr 01, 2016' &sqlQueryID=daily_runs"
```

Result : 0 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the date format as mentioned in the [Where Clause Examples](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where)
`where date '2005-01-21' < hireDate`

in your select statement, format `startDate` and `endDate` as `YYYY-MM-DD` and prefix with `date`

i.e. `select * where execution_date >= date '" + startDate + "' ...`